# Need to post multi dimensional JSON from Angularjs form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

i'm new in angular. i need multi dimensional type json. mycode is given below

view page controller

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.menu  = {};
        $scope.menus  = [
  {"menuID":"1","sub_menu":"N","name":"dashboard","sub_menus":""},
  {"menuID":"2","sub_menu":"Y","name":"settings","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"settings1","page":"Y","pages":[{"pageID":"1","name":"page1"},{"pageID":"2","name":"page2"}]},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"settings2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
  {"menuID":"3","sub_menu":"Y","name":"help","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"help1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"help2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
  {"menuID":"4","sub_menu":"Y","name":"contact","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"contact1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"contact2","page":"N","pages":""}]}
 ];

 $scope.submit = function(){
  // alert(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
  console.error(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
 }
 
});


html view page
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>rules</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mainCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in menus">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="menu[x.menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{x.menuID}}'">{{x.name}}
          <ul ng-if="[x.sub_menu] == 'Y'">
            <li ng-repeat="subMenu in x.sub_menus">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="menu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID]">{{subMenu.name}}
              <ul ng-if="[subMenu.page] == 'Y'">
                <li ng-repeat="page in subMenu.pages">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="menu[x.name][subMenu.name][page.pageID]">{{page.name}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need this format of JSON:

[image]

After all checkbox checked and post form.

Comment: If we help, would you mark the right answer?

Comment: Please add your sample JSON in as formatted text, not an image - it is much easier to read as text.

Comment: {
    "1":"1",
    "2":{
            "1":{
                    "1":"1",
                    "2":"2"
            },
            "2":"2",
            "3":"3",
            "4":"4"
    },
    "3":{
            "5":"5",
            "6":"6",
            "7":"7",
            "8":"8"
    },
    "4":{
            "9":"9",
            "10":"10"
    },
    "5":"5",
    "6":"6",
    "7":"7",
    "8":"8",
    "9":"9",    
    "10":"10"
}

Comment: Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 6
            [7] => 7
            [8] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [9] => 9
            [10] => 10
        )

    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 10
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in snippet will create the object structure as per requirement if all check boxes selected. But it will change only value to false if user unchecked boxes(you can work upon this as per requirement in future).

Please see the below snippet for answer.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mainMenu = {};
  $scope.submenu = {};
  $scope.pagemenu ={};
 $scope.menu  = {};
        $scope.menus  = [
  {"menuID":"1","sub_menu":"N","name":"dashboard","sub_menus":""},
  {"menuID":"2","sub_menu":"Y","name":"settings","sub_menus":             [{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"settings1","page":"Y","pages":[{"pageID":"1","name":"page1"},{"pageID":"2","name":"page2"}]},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"settings2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
  {"menuID":"3","sub_menu":"Y","name":"help","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"help1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"help2","page":"N","pages":""}]},
  {"menuID":"4","sub_menu":"Y","name":"contact","sub_menus":[{"sub_menuID":"1","name":"contact1","page":"N","pages":""},{"sub_menuID":"2","name":"contact2","page":"N","pages":""}]}
 ];
  
  $scope.assignValue = function(menuId,submenuId,pageId){
/*  if(!$scope.mainMenu[menuId]&&!$scope.submenu[menuId]&&!$scope.pagemenu[menuId]){
    delete($scope.mainMenu[menuId]);
    delete($scope.submenu[menuId]);
    delete($scope.pagemenu[menuId]);
  }*/

if(pageId!=undefined && !$scope.pagemenu[menuId][submenuId][pageId]){
    delete($scope.pagemenu[menuId][submenuId][pageId]);
    if(Object.keys($scope.pagemenu[menuId][submenuId]).length === 0){
       delete($scope.pagemenu[menuId][submenuId]);
  }
  }
  
  if(submenuId!=undefined && $scope.submenu[menuId][submenuId]!=undefined && !$scope.submenu[menuId][submenuId] && Object.keys($scope.submenu[menuId][submenuId]).length === 0){
    delete($scope.submenu[menuId][submenuId]);
   
  }

    if(Object.keys($scope.menu).length === 0){
        $scope.menu=Object.assign({},$scope.mainMenu,$scope.submenu);
    }else{
        $scope.menu[menuId] = $scope.mainMenu[menuId];
    }
  
    var tempObj = Object.assign({},$scope.submenu[menuId],$scope.pagemenu[menuId]);
    if(Object.keys(tempObj).length != 0){
        $scope.menu[menuId] = tempObj
    }
  
  
  console.log($scope.menu);
  }
  

 $scope.submit = function(){
  // alert(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.menu));
     console.log($scope.menu);
 }
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>rules</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mainCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in menus">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID)" ng-model="mainMenu[x.menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{x.menuID}}'">{{x.name}}
          <ul ng-if="[x.sub_menu] == 'Y'">
            <li ng-repeat="subMenu in x.sub_menus">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="submenu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID]" ng-true-value="'{{subMenu.sub_menuID}}'" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,null)">{{subMenu.name}}
              <ul ng-if="[subMenu.page] == 'Y'">
                <li ng-repeat="page in subMenu.pages">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pagemenu[x.menuID][subMenu.sub_menuID][page.pageID]"  ng-true-value="'{{page.pageID}}'" ng-change= "assignValue(x.menuID,subMenu.sub_menuID,page.pageID)">{{page.name}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, Dhiraj it doesn't give proper value

Comment: could you provide some steps for producing wrong value.?

Comment: when select menu and sub menu it  gives:-
{
  "1": "1",
  "2": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
  },
  "3": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
  },
  "4": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
  }
}

Comment: when all box selected it gives :- 
{
  "1": "1",
  "2": {
    "1": {
      "1": "1",
      "2": "2"
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
  },
  "4": {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "2"
  }
}
here sub menu 2 missing

Comment: The checkbox which are already checked, if  uncheck them then they give key and  false value too.I need to remove all keys which are not checked

Comment: So u need to implement the delete logic. I will try to add this logic in this snippet soon

Comment: Thanks @Dhiraj. you are life saver